# Use VBA to check for text before taking action without selecting text

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to only take action if the document contains a specific word/phrase.  The first part of my macro inserts texts and then I want to check for a word to see if the macro continues. If the document already has the word I want the cursor to be at the end of the inserted text.

I don't want the specific word selected when the macro runs. Below is what I have so far but it selects the word.

```
Selection.HomeKey Unit:wdStory
With Selection.Find
  .ClearFormatting
  .Text = "Hello"
End With

If Not Selection.Find.Execute Then
    Action
End If
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's actually a quite elegant and easy way to do this. Instead of using `Selection` do the Find using a `Range`. Think of a `Range` like an invisible selection, but with two major advantages:

- The selection doesn't change. Code is faster; the screen doesn't flicker
- Code can use as many `Range` objects as necessary; there can only ever be *one* Selection

For example:

```
Dim rngFind as Word.Range
Dim found as Boolean

Set rngFind = ActiveDocument.Content

With rngFind.Find
  .ClearFormatting
  .Text = "Hello"
  found = .Execute
End With

If Not found Then
    'Actions here
End If
```